# Display datas with Axios (React Native)

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to display data that I fetched with Axios. They came as an array. Because of this I cant show them. What should I do?

Here is my fetch code

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.post('http://192.168.1.106:80/partner_project_backend/project_list.php')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

Here is my console.log

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are getting the API response correctly and your only intention is to display the data in your application. If so, you could use the `FlatList` component from `React Native`

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://192.168.1.106:80/partner_project_backend/project_list.php')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ data: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>{item.name}</Text> // render your view here
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

React more about FlatList at https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data you have to use `get` method NOT `post`

```
this.state ={ data : null }

componentDidMount(){
axios.get('http://192.168.1.106:80/partner_project_backend/project_list.php')
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({ data : response.data })
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: I fix the post problem but still can't display the data. ‍♀️

Comment: Use State like here  `this.state ={ data : null }` and assign the res to the data like this `this.setState({ data : response.data })`